# NSDictionary Strange Behaviour with NSString key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

```
NSString *downloadedItemIDString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"downloadedItemIDString = %@", downloadedItemIDString);

if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:downloadedItemIDString] != nil)
      NSLog(@"1) Item WITH ID %@ EXISTS!", downloadedItemIDString);
if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:@"6226691114401792"] != nil)
      NSLog(@"2) Item WITH ID 6226691114401792 EXISTS!");
```

Log :

> 2014-04-15 20:51:37.336 AppDemo[2201:60b] downloadedItemIDString = 6226691114401792
>   2014-04-15 20:51:37.337 AppDemo[2201:60b] 2) Item WITH ID 6226691114401792 EXISTS!

I'm new to Obj C and I've been trying to solve this for hours..Please help me understand why it does not find the object when supplied NSString as the key?

Comment: There's probably some whitespace on the id value. Add quotes int the log statement to be sure: `NSLog(@"downloadedItemIDString = '%@'", downloadedItemIDString);` and see if any spaces appear.

Comment: 2014-04-15 21:05:19.314 AppDemo[2232:60b] downloadedItemIDString = '6226691114401792'
2014-04-15 21:05:19.315 AppDemo[2232:60b] 2) Item WITH ID '6226691114401792' EXISTS!

Comment: I've added the '' but still mystery.. :/

Comment: One more test: Add the following log: `NSLog(@"downloadedItemIDString class = %@", [downloadedItemIDString class]);`.

Comment: `downloadedItemIDString` might not be an NSString but a NSNumber instead.

Comment: uhh its __NSCFNumber.. how did it get to that state, how do I transform it to NSString

Comment: You're asking us how your value isn't what you expect? It's your code. How did you put the value in `dict`?

Comment: I'm assuming (because your question really lacks info) that "dict" is created by parsing a JSON file? If the "id" in that JSON file had no quotes around the number, JSON parser is gonna figure it's a number and give you a number instead of a string

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys! Yes dict was created by parsing a JSON data.

Comment: Probably wouldn't run into that issue if you removed `!= nil`, and simply had `if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:downloadedItemIDString])` and `if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:@"6226691114401792"])`.  Mind you, it's always good to make sure you know exactly what you're comparing.

Comment: @Karah that's not true, dictionary will ***not*** return an object for key of NSNumber kind if the actual key used in that dictionary was NSString.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *downloadedItemIDString = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
NSLog(@"downloadedItemIDString = %@", downloadedItemIDString);
if([downloadedItemIDString isEqualToString:@"6226691114401792"])
{
    if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:downloadedItemIDString] != nil)
        NSLog(@"1) Item WITH ID %@ EXISTS!", downloadedItemIDString);
if([storedRecordsDict objectForKey:@"6226691114401792"] != nil)
    NSLog(@"2) Item WITH ID 6226691114401792 EXISTS!");
}
```

First of all check your downloadedItemIDString is equal to @"6226691114401792" then both if condition will execute.